# Where to call the function ..?

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual

I am new to plugin development/editing with Wordpress. I am using a famous plugin called Polylang for multilingual support.
And I am using another plugin called Clean and Simple contact form for creating an AJAX based contact form.

Now, looking into the documentation for Polylang I have found the following function:

**Register String**
Allows plugins to add their own strings in the “strings translation” panel. The function must be called on admin side (the functions.php file is OK for themes).
Usage:

```
pll_register_string($name, $string, $multiline);
```

As it says, function must be called on admin side. I am unable to figure out what that means ...

I intend to add a few custom strings to the strings translation tab. Calling this function from functions.php in the theme worked but didn't translate strings from the plugin. The plugin doesn't yet support Japanese so I am having to take this path.

Can you tell me where exactly am I supposed to call this function. I tried to call it in class.view.php  and the file with the name: clean-and-simple-contact-form-by-meg-nicholas.php

But, both ended up giving a fatal error saying that the function is undefined. What's the exact meaning of "The function must be called on admin side of a plugin..."

Thanks and Regards !

Answer (score 1):

You might need to adjust your ajax plugin, so the function gets called in the admin. (I don't really know the ajax plugin but I am sure that there is some configuration part, which will be called somewhere in the admin panel)
Another way would be to create another plugin, which is just taking care of that function call. Just be sure, that this new plugin has some link you can call from the admin, so it is run in the right userspace.

Comment: I am really sorry but can you please explain the meaning of:
"so the function gets called in the admin." ..?

Comment: Take for example a plugin, where you have a settings page in the admin panel. This settings page is called 'in the admin'